# Limit mouse movement within 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a circle sprite that i only want to move between 2 empty game objects (points). Using Vector3.Lerp() I'm able to move the circle between those points

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float speed = 10 * Time.deltaTime;
    float current = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint.position, endPoint.position, current);
}
```

The output:
[image: What I currently have with lerp]

**The problem:**

I want to move that circle using a mouse drag (basically like a slider from point a to point b) and as soon as the mouse leaves the circle to stop moving it

**What I've tried:**

- I have tried adding a gameobject with a box collider between the two points and using triggers to detect when the circle exits the trigger
  (OnTriggerExit2D), but this solution only works when the circle fully leaves the collider (which i don't want). I want a way for the circle to move just like its moving currently with Vector3.Lerp but with mouse control
- I tried locking the circle to only one axis and moving it. While this worked, it failed when i rotated the whole slider as its only locked on one axis and rotation doesn't change that
- I have also tried to implement the mouse position into the Vector3.Lerp function with no luck
  `Vector3.Lerp(startPoint.position, endPoint.position, mousePosition.x);`

  I tried with y and z, all of it failed. And this way wouldn't work when i go to rotate the slider

Comment: Can you please further explain how you are trying to move the circle? while clicking on the circle, hovering over it, etc...

Comment: Its very simple actually. You need to check if mouse click is performed then do what you want like move the circle. You also need t Raycast to check the mouse pointer position to drag the circle along. Check this article http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/10/move-to-mouse-click-touch-position-unity.html. This is on pointer click. Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152525/drag-object-in-unity-2d.

Comment: @Saeleas you click on the circle and start dragging, if your pointer leaves the circle stop dragging (even if the mouse is still clicked). What I'm trying to do is make a custom Slider that moves a circle between 2 points

Comment: @SaadAnees I reviewed both links and they don't match the question. I can already move the circle around with a mouse click. What i want to do is limit that movement to only 1 line (between point1 and point2)

Comment: You mean you want to move horizontally but not vertically?

Comment: @Saad Anees Exactly, i only want to be able to move the circle in a straight line from point a to point b using the mouse. These points can be set at an angle so the movement sometimes can be vertical (Just like a UI slider)

Comment: Then i dont see issue here. You are already doing it i guess. There are severals ways to achieve that. If your problem is vertical axis then just fix the y axis in vector3 and increment x axis value.

Comment: @Saad Anees the thing is its not just vertical or horizontal. I want the circle to move (mouse drag) between those 2 points no matter how i place them.

Comment: Okay i got you i think. You only want move circle with mousedrag. Right?

Comment: @SaadAnees Yes and i want it to move in a straight line between the 2 points, not freely on the screen

Comment: SO @SenaCarbtc you can achieve this with the 2nd link I shared with you. Its the same thing you want. Moving object with Dragging mouse pointer.